# Industrial machines lose connectivity when one is powered off

Tags: ethernet, lan

I am working with 2 identical industrial machines with multiple Ethernet switches per machine. The basic layout looks like this:

```
Switch 1 Machine A -> Switch 2 Machine A -> Switch 4 Machine A
                  |-> Switch 3 Machine A
                  \-> Switch 1 Machine B -> Switch 2 Machine B -> Switch 4 Machine B
                                        \-> Switch 3 Machine B
```

I double checked every Ethernet cable in the machines and confirmed there are no loops

Each switch has multiple devices on it (some of which are daisy chained) All the switches are Allen Bradley Stratix 5700 Industrial Managed Ethernet Switches that have IPs set but no other settings modified from the defaults.

When we power down Machine B (including all of the Machine B switches) connection is lost between our PLC which is on Machine A Switch 1 and our safety inputs which are on Machine A switch 2

Why would I be loosing this connectivity? It takes about 30 seconds for all the devices to reconnect and stops Machine A from working until it is all back online. Why would it only be this way? I do not see the same behavior on machine B when I power off Machine A. Is there something I can do from the managed switch side to force the information on a certain path so that the loss of Machine B's switches doesn't cause connectivity loss?

Thanks

Comment: It seems those switches have some spanning-tree protocol activated by default - have you set a root switch in your network? Have you checked the switch log?

Comment: @Zac67 There is no loop so how can there be Spanning Tree? I thought Spanning Tree was to set up redundancies in case of link failures?   No there is no Root Switch set.  I tried to recreate the problem to see if it added entries into the SYSLOG but this time it was fine on power down and lost connection on power up. There were no new entries in the SYSLOG

Comment: Even though there are no loops, spanning tree is still blocking ports when the root disappears.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to Network Engineering!  The 30 second loss of connectivity is a strong indication that spanning-tree is causing problems.   If a switch on B is the root, switch A will block all ports when it no longer "hears" the root switch.

You should:

1. Set the all the switch's STP mode to Rapid Spanning Tree.
2. Set all the ports excepts those that link switches to PortFast.
3. Set switch 1 Machine A to be the spanning tree root.

You can also turn off spanning tree **IF and ONLY IF** you are sure you can't create a loop by inadvertently connecting two switches together.

Comment: Makes sense. I see the settings to change to Rapid Spanning Tree and to set which ports are using PortFast but I am not seeing how to set up tree root. I have a table with 1 row where the only editable fields are Enable check box and Priority. [See Here](https://i.imgur.com/VIeIAPY.png)

Comment: The switch with the lowest priority becomes the root.  Set the root switch priority to 4096.

Comment: What happens with a tie in priority? Wouldn't changing the root to be in Machine A make the same problem just with the machines swapped: If Machine A shuts off then Machine B fails to communicate. I think it is safe to say there will be no loops so I am fine with turning off spanning, I would just like to understand more.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  B will block, although with RSTP that will be just a second or two.  In case of a tie, the switch with the lowest MAC address becomes the root.

Comment: Makes sense. However because we are doing safety devices over Ethernet being down for a second stops the machine. I disabled the Spanning Tree and the problem resolved. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Evan If these safety devices cannot cope with a connectivty loss of 1sec without bailing out, then the choice of ethernet might not be the right one. An Ehernet topology with multiple switches and without Spanning Tree must be pendantically set up and maintained and documented  and ALL unused ports disabled/shut down. At the first occurrence of a loop, the whole network will die a horrible death, within seconds. Be sure that you know what you're doing...

Comment: @Marc'netztier'Luethi A loss in connectivity results in the shutdown of all hazardous energy. Ethernet Safety is a pretty standard practice in modern industry. [Here is more reading on the I/O devices if you are interested](https://ab.rockwellautomation.com/IO/1734-POINT-Guard-IO-Modules). I have not considered disabling unused ports to avoid loops and that is a good idea. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Evan Thanks for the pointers. Looking (in cursory fashion) at their _EtherNet/IP Embedded Switch Technology - Application Guide_, actually replaced by a document called _EtherNet/IP Device Level Ring -  Application Technique_ paper, I get the impression that they have something else in mind than classical switched Ethernet with (rapid) spanning tree as loop prevention and redundancy mechanism. If these papers apply to your intended setup, I'd suggest considering their "native" solution for the purpose: ring topology with their ring controller node(s).

Comment: @Evan You're also mentioning "hazardous energy" . Mixed with Ethernet-with-no-spanning-tree (which also implies that the network will NOT have any redundant paths to compensate for link or device failure), this would put me at unease. I really suggest to go with what the vendor proposes as their preferred LAN topology.